# How do I set my text like this in React Native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I have tried textAlign="center" but it only aligns the text in the center but I want to align the whole text in the center including the last line

```
  <Text
      style={{
         marginTop: 16,
         alignSelf: 'center',
         fontSize: 15,
         width: '75%',
         textAlignVertical: 'center',
         justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
            Making a luxurious lifestyle accessible for a generous group of
            women is our daily drive.
  </Text>
```

Comment: Please post some code on what have you actually tried on implementing that

Comment: <Text
            style={{
              marginTop: 16,
              alignSelf: 'center',
              fontSize: 15,
              width: '75%',
              textAlignVertical: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            Making a luxurious lifestyle accessible for a generous group of
            women is our daily drive.
          </Text>

Comment: @VishvasPatel please add more code what you did to make the end line (styled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full example. please read about textAlign property.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text
        style={styles.text}>
        Making a luxurious lifestyle accessible for a generous group of
        women is our daily drive.
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:"center",
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  text:{
      marginTop: 16,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign:"center",
      width: '75%',
      textAlignVertical: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: Since SO doesn't support RN, you can alternatively use https://snack.expo.dev for working example: https://snack.expo.dev/Sx8MOSQXI. Not required but it offers a good way to proof your solution